# ng-click to display user info

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm very new to javascript and angularjs and im trying to do something very basic. I want to display info about the specific user i click on.

I have a list of users that i display like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser()">
                <td>{{user.FirstName}} {{user.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
                <td>{{user.RegistrationDate | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</td>
            </tr>
```

on the click event right now, there is just an alert. The method in my webapi looks like GetUser(int id) and i have no problem getting the data.

this is what my js controller looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/api/controllerName')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.error = "Couldnt load data or there was none.";
        }
                    )
    //$scope.selectedUser = function () {
    //    $http.get()
    //}

    $scope.selectUser = function () {
        alert("Some text");
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Hello, you are just making a small mistake on the ng-click make sure to make it like ng-click="selectUser()"

Answer (score 0):

I don't get how exactly you want to show your data, but when I want to do something like that I do this:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="user in users" ng-click="user.display = !user.display">
    <td>{{user.FirstName}} {{user.LastName}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show='user.display'>
    <td>
        <div>
            <p>{{user.Email}}</p>
            <p>{{user.RegistrationDate | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in Angular

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/api/controllerName').then(function(data){
        var users = data;
        for(i in users){
            users[i].display = false;
        }
        $scope.users = users;
    }, function(){
        $scope.error = "Couldnt load data or there was none.";
    });
}]);
```

Angular `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` allows you to repeat different tags using the same data, which to what you want can be very useful. 
`ng-show`display the tag if his param is true.
Hope it helps.

[ngRepeat Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

[ngShow Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: Right now before moving on, i'm trying to see if i just can get the same data that i already see into the alert. Maybe thats not possible? Thanks for your answer, I will have a look at it.

Comment: You want to click at the row and then return the data that you are already displaying? If so, you just have to do another $http request inside your `selectUser` and call it with `ng-click='selectUser()'`

Comment: Sort of, but I only want the data for that specific user i'm clicking on to display.

Comment: So `ng-repeat='user in users'` `ng-click='selectUser(user.id)'` together at the `<tr>` and the `$scope.selectUser = function selectUser(id){$http.get("/get/user/api"+id) ... }` should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example with toggle functionality when click on user name show hide other information. http://jsfiddle.net/Adalsingh/5n1ggovh/

```js
var data = [{FirstName:'f1',LastName:'l1',Email:'e1',RegistrationDate:'2015-01-20',showData:false},{FirstName:'f2',LastName:'l2',Email:'E2',RegistrationDate:'2015-01-21',showData:false},{FirstName:'f3',LastName:'l3',Email:'e3',RegistrationDate:'2015-01-22',showData:false}];

angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.users = data;
    /*
    $http.get('/api/controllerName')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.error = "Couldnt load data or there was none.";
        });
    */
    
    $scope.selectUser = function (obj) {
        if(obj.showData)
            obj.showData = false;
        else
            obj.showData = true;
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="userCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user)">
                <td style="cursor:pointer">{{user.FirstName}} {{user.LastName}}</td>
                <td ng-show="user.showData">{{user.Email}}</td>
                <td ng-show="user.showData">{{user.RegistrationDate | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```